# Jersey: How to get POST parameters on server side?

Tags: java, web-services, jax-rs

I used to tried @QueryParam when i pass parameters on url
and also @PathParam after that i just try to call by http protocal. It doesn't work.

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/putOtdDebt")
public Response putOtdDebt(@HeaderParam("username") String username,                                 
                           @HeaderParam("password") String password) {

     System.out.println("username: " + username);
     System.out.println("password: " + password);
     return Response.status(201).entity("{\"testStr\": \"Call putOtdDebt\"}").build();
    }
```

and i tried to call like this:

```
Client client = Client.create();

WebResource webResource = client
              .resource("http://localhost:8080/BgsRestService/rest/bgs/putOtdDebt");

String input = "{\"username\":\"testuser\",\"password\":\"testpassword\"}";

ClientResponse response = webResource.type("application/json")
               .post(ClientResponse.class, input);
if (response.getStatus() != 201) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                     + response.getStatus());
            }

System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
String output = response.getEntity(String.class);
System.out.println(output);
```

result is parameters are null:

```
username: null
password: null

help me! how can i get post parameters?
```

Comment: What do you mean by “POST parameter”?

Comment: i put parameters like this "{\"username\":\"testuser\",\"password\":\"testpassword\"}" and i want to get this parameters on POST method using @HeaderParam("username") but doesn't work

Comment: You obviously have no clue as to what you’re doing. Good luck.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar What do you mean? can't i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `input` string as a body in `POST` call

```
String input = "{\"username\":\"testuser\",\"password\":\"testpassword\"}";
```

And in server side code you are using `@HeaderParam` to get the values from body which is incorrect, `@HeaderParam` are used to get header values

**public @interface HeaderParam**

> Binds the value(s) of a HTTP header to a resource method parameter, resource class field, or resource class bean property.

You can accept the `POST` body as string, if you want to get `username` and `password` you need to parse string into `JsonObject` and get the values

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/putOtdDebt")
public Response putOtdDebt(String body) {

 System.out.println("body: " + body);
  }
```

Or you can also create POJO with these two properties and map it directly

```
public class Pojo {

 private String username;
 private String password;
 //getters and setters
  }
```

**Server code**

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/putOtdDebt")
public Response putOtdDebt(Pojo body) {

System.out.println("username: " + body.getUsername());
System.out.println("password: " + body.getPassword());
  }
```